# MobileServiceCollection data binding to listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm working on an app connected to windows azure. I have a listbox that will display project names. The connection made with azure works and I get valid results, but the listbox doesn't seem to get updated (visually). It works if I add an observable collection and add the projects into this collection with the listbox correctly connected.

Any idea why this isn't working?

This is my code:

```
    public MobileServiceCollection<Project, Project> Projects { get; private set; }
    private IMobileServiceTable<Project> projectTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Project>();        

    public async void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            Projects = await projectTable
                .Where(Project => Project.ID != 0)
                .ToCollectionAsync();
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error loading projects", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind your Projects MobileServiceCollection to your Listbox just like you would bind an ObservableColleciton

```
try
    {
        Projects = await projectTable
            .Where(Project => Project.ID != 0)
            .ToCollectionAsync();

        //Bind Projects to ListBox
        ListBox.ItemsSource = Projects;
    }
```

Additionally as you use the IMobileServiceTable to insert/update/delete Projects you must keep your MobileServiceCollection in sync by updating the collection

```
        //Add a new project to the database
        await projectTable.InsertAsync(project);

        //Update the collection to match the database
        Projects.Add(project);
```